# Android views in fragments overlapping

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

So I've read several tutorials and many of the posts on SO but I still can't get this to work. I'm trying to use dynamically added fragments but when loading a fragment TextViews and ImageViews in the fragment keep overlapping instead of updating their values, like so:
[image]

and fragments overlap each other when replaced.

I got a main activity (extending AppCompatActivity) split into 2 layouts:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_white"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/upperFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/lowerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
...
```

The upper FrameLayout contains my fragments. The fragments are replaced in this method in the MainActivity-class:

```
void setMode() {
    // Show "find opponent"- or "fight"-fragment
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (!debugFight && (btCoordinator == null || !btCoordinator.isConnected())) {
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.upperFrameLayout, new FindOpponentFragment());
    } else {
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.upperFrameLayout, new FightFragment());
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commitNow();
}
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: Added FightFragment onCreateView()-method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ((TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fight, container, false).findViewById(R.id.score_textView)).setText(getString(R.string.score, 0, 0));
    ((TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fight, container, false).findViewById(R.id.opponent_textView)).setText(MainActivity.opponentName.toUpperCase());

    final AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat animated = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(container.getContext(), R.drawable.loading_animated_vector);
    animated.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
            animated.start();
        }
    });
    ((ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fight, container, false).findViewById(R.id.opponent_hand_imageview)).setImageDrawable(animated);
    animated.start();

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fight, container, false);
}
```

...and as I pasted this piece of code I just realised that those inflated views are all different objects. I replaced them with a single object which I modify and then let the method return and it works. I guess I have to read up on views and the inflate-method.

Comment: Can you include your `onCreate()` method?

Comment: Add `android:background="@color/background_white"` to the rootview of your fragment and check again. Make sure the value of color/background_white is not transparent.

Comment: @PrashantJha This solved the overlapping but now only the textviews with the placeholder string is visible and not the layout with the correct strings in the textviews.

Comment: Is it the issue of text color now? Check the text color of your `TextView` once.

Comment: Please post the complete layout file and sample screen shot, if possible.

Comment: @PrashantJha It was a problem related to my fragments onCreateView-method because I didn't understand what how inflating works.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank you. Just you mentioning it made me look closer on my onCreateView-method and that's where I done goofed.

Answer (score 0):

use fragmentTransaction. add() instead of replace()

Answer (score 0):

Use this above the fragment commit

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand how the inflate-method. I modified my fragments onCreateView-method as seen in the OP and now it works.